# (Monetate) Breadcrumb menu using HTML/CSS/jQuery - Fixing the slight delay between transition of the <a> element and the transition of the CSS arrow

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to code a breadcrumb-type checkout progress indicator using the code produced by the really awesome generator developed by [Jonas Ohlsson](https://codepen.io/pocketjoso/pen/foLAd). It uses a combination of HTML, CSS and jQuery and it's applied to my site using Monetate (loading asynchronously). When a user is on whatever stage of the checkout, that particular stage is highlighted. When a user hovers over one of the stages that isn't the current stage, it's also highlighted but in a different colour.

So far, so good. It works perfectly, bar one problem. 
The  element and the arrow to the right of it is supposed to fade in for 0.15s on hover, then fade out again on mouse out.
The transition works as you would expect on the  element itself, but not on the arrows. In the generator, they both animate at the same time, but when I run it on my site it looks a bit off. It also works totally fine when I run it on StackOverflow.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Here are a few code snippets of the HTML and CSS as the JS works fine, if anything sticks out as odd or erroneous I'd really appreciate a few pointers!

```css
/*Theming options - change and everything updates*/
/*don't use more decimals, as it makes browser round errors more likely, make heights unmatching
-also watch using decimals at all at low wizardSize font sizes!*/
.checkout-progress-breadcrumbs {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1% 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  line-height: 1;
}
/*base item styles*/
.crumb-step {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .15s;
  /*default styles*/
  background-color: #e5ecdf;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
/*arrow styles*/
.crumb-step:before,
.crumb-step:after {
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-width: 1em 0 1em 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  transition: all .15s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
/*arrow overlapping left side of item*/
.crumb-step:before {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
  left: 0;
}
/*arrow pointing out from right side of items*/
.crumb-step:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #e5ecdf;
  z-index: 1;
}
/*current item styles*/
.step-selected.crumb-step {
  background-color: #8BA870;
  color: white;
  cursor: default;
}
.step-selected.crumb-step:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #8BA870;
}
/*hover styles*/
.crumb-step:not(.step-selected):hover {
  background-color: #becfaf;
}
.crumb-step:not(.step-selected):hover:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #becfaf;
}
/*remove arrows from beginning and end*/
.crumb-step:first-of-type:before,
.crumb-step:last-of-type:after {
  border-color: transparent !important;
}
/*no inset arrow for first item*/
.crumb-step:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 0.25em 0 0 0.25em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
}
/*no protruding arrow for last item*/
.crumb-step:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 0.25em 0.25em 0;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkout-progress-breadcrumbs">
  <a class="crumb-step" href="/checkout/step/1" id="basket-step">1. My Bag </a> 
  <a class="crumb-step" href="/checkout/step/2" id="details-step">2. Details </a> 
  <a class="crumb-step" href="/checkout/step/3" id="delivery-step">3. Delivery </a> 
  <a class="crumb-step" href="/checkout/step/4" id="payment-step">4. Payment </a>
</div>
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Pretty tough to debug something that we can't reproduce.

Comment: @Our_Benefactors that's fair enough, it may well be a Monetate-specific problem. Unfortunately I can't create a new tag for Monetate as I don't have the rep.

Comment: Everything looks perfectly fine, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Thanks for your response!

That's what's left me so stumped, really. It runs fine on here, and it runs fine in the original generator. But when I load it up on my site, the two are out of sync. I've attempted to adjust the transition times in both directions to compensate for this weird delay to no avail. This leads me to believe it's a Monetate thing. I'm curious to see if anyone has ever encountered this before, either when using Monetate or while developing in general.

Comment: If you've deployed it, a link to it would be really great

Comment: @TheDarkKnight at the moment I can't push it to live, I can only view it in preview, or I can push it to a specific IP if that's of any use.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was an inherited transition, so I wanted to point this out in case any more Monetate users come across this problem. Links on this particular page inherited a set of 400ms transitions I didn't spot:

```
.checkout_template a {
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color 400ms ease-in-out,color 400ms ease-in-out; }
```

So to override this, I needed to include the following:

```
.checkout_template a {
    -moz-transition: none !important;
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    -o-transition: all 0 ease-in !important;
    transition: none !important; }
```

As with a lot of things in Monetate, "!important" is necessary despite not being best practice.